# toggling action in checkboxes in React-Redux doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, redux, react-redux, react-router

Hello i have problem with my action in Redux. I want will check single checkbox and if it will be clicked, my state will change

**FOR EXAMPLE**: if i click on second element my value will change. Other elements will doesnt change 
if i have state[0].question[0].answers[1].checked = true || false if i will click 2x in the same place

***will be helpful***:
**state** - I have state which is arr and have some objects inside *(https://github.com/RetupK/QuizApp/blob/master/src/store/quiz/quizReducer.js)*

**actions creators** - *(https://github.com/RetupK/QuizApp/blob/master/src/actions/quiz/quizActions.js)*
**quizId** - it depends on what we quiz we will choose. ***It is Routing match parametr***. here is our routing *(https://github.com/RetupK/QuizApp/blob/master/src/App.js)*
 here is our Component and showed how i did mapDispatchToProps and how i connected this with view *(https://github.com/RetupK/QuizApp/blob/master/src/containers/quizContainer.js)*
 
**activeQuestion** - it is which question is active this is **local state in component**.

Someone know how to resolve this problem with doesnt working this action?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I'm not able to understand this correctly. As far as I could understand, you need to implement a toggle system based on your state.

Say you have an initial state that looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
    toggle: false,
}
```

In your switch statement inside your reducer you can do something like this:

```
const yourReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
    case TOGGLE: 
        return {...state, toggle: !state.toggle}
    default:
        return initialState
    }
}
```

And you can dispatch your action inside react in your onClick event handler so every time you click that element it's gonna return either `true` or `false` based on your state.

UPDATE: Now in your case, since your state is an array and you want to return your state based on an id or index you can try doing something like this:

```js
//in your reducer switch() case
return state.map((e, i) =>{
     if (i === indexYourLookingFor) return {...e, checked: !e.checked};
     else return e;
})
```

That way you can preserve your state array immutability. You can check for more patterns in the official redux documentation [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).

Comment: I have toggle inside state for each question 

answers: [
                    { id: 1, content: "Tasadsad", checked: false, points: 1 },
                    { id: 1, content: "Nisadasde", checked: false, points: 0 },
                    { id: 1, content: "Nie asdwiem", checked: false, points: 0 },
                ]

I want change single checked after click checkbox with id